# Remove slashes from a string which is forming as array in java

Tags: java, android

I have a JSON response. In that JSON block there is a string which contains slash (\), I have tried solutions available to remove unwanted data in the string but no success.

this is the string i want to deal with

```
"[{\"date\": \"2019-05-14\",\"quantity\": \"55\"},{\"date\": \"2019-05-15\",\"quantity\": \"58\"},{\"date\": \"2019-05-16\",\"quantity\": \"50\"}]"
```

the entire json is :

```
{
    "Address": "Durga Nagar",
    "Area": "West aerodrome",
    "BookingDate": "1970-01-01",
    "BookingDetails": "[{\"date\": \"2019-05-14\",\"quantity\": \"55\"},{\"date\": \"2019-05-15\",\"quantity\": \"58\"},{\"date\": \"2019-05-16\",\"quantity\": \"50\"}]",
    "noOfBoxes": null,
    "createdAT": "2019-03-29 07:48:07",
    "ModifiedAT": "2019-03-29 07:48:07"
},
```

I want to remove only slash.

Comment: Do not send json as string from the server side

Comment: which library are you using for getting data

Comment: I assume you're aware of String's replaceAll method?

Comment: just want those initial double quotes and slashes

Comment: yes.. i have tried but no luck @St

Comment: If you implemented the server side yourself, you shouldn't send the BookingDetails as a json string and rather just add it as a json array. If you can't work around this, get the BookingDetails as a string, and then run in through the json parser again

Comment: To add to this: Never try to transform **valid** json using string manipulation. Use a json parser

Comment: If you require further assistance with this, show us the code you use to parse the json, and show us the code you use to generate the json (if available)

Comment: Your string is being json encoded more than one time thus it is adding extra slashes. ask your api team to look into this or post relevant code here.

Comment: That json string is coming from server side. send only json array data. or you can try to parse that json String using JSON Parser here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import java.io.FileReader; 
    import org.json.simple.JSONObject; 
    import org.json.simple.parser.*; 

        public class Example 
        { 
            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
            { 
                // parsing file "JSONExample.json" 
                Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("/Users/dell/Documents/JSONExample.json"));          
                // typecasting obj to JSONObject 
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj; 

                // getting json filds
                String firstName = (String) jo.get("Address"); 
                String lastName = (String) jo.get("Area"); 
                String BookingDate = (String) jo.get("BookingDate"); 

                String BookingDetails = (String) jo.get("BookingDetails"); 
                String noOfBoxes = (String) jo.get("noOfBoxes"); 
                String createdAT = (String) jo.get("createdAT"); 
                String ModifiedAT = (String) jo.get("ModifiedAT"); 

                System.out.println(firstName); 
                System.out.println(lastName); 
                System.out.println(BookingDate); 
                System.out.println(BookingDetails); 
                System.out.println(noOfBoxes); 
                System.out.println(createdAT); 
                System.out.println(ModifiedAT); 

            } 
        } 

result of this file is 
Durga Nagar
West aerodrome
1970-01-01
[{"date": "2019-05-14","quantity": "55"},{"date": "2019-05-15","quantity": "58"},{"date": "2019-05-16","quantity": "50"}]
null
2019-03-29 07:48:07
2019-03-29 07:48:07
```

Answer (score 0):

`String ss="[{\"date\": \"2019-05-14\",\"quantity\": \"55\"},{\"date\": \"2019-05-15\",\"quantity\": \"58\"},{\"date\": \"2019-05-16\",\"quantity\": \"50\"}]";

String replace = ss.replace('\', ' ');`

Comment: use replace('\\',' ')